# Simulate non-existing 3D Driver

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

I'm currently developing a 3D-based Application (In C++, if that matters). To test special circumstances, I also need to test the behaviour when no 3D Interface could be loaded (e.g, `glutInit()` failed).

The environment is currently Linux, so a Linux-based solution would be preferable.

How would I test a case where no 3D Interface could be created, without unloading the binary 3D driver from my kernel (which is nVidia)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running the application under something like a VNC server, or Xnest. Those don't generally support OpenGL.

Answer (score 1):

Run it under a virtual machine using VMware or VirtualBox.